# Understanding a trivial invariant measure on $\mathbb R$: An Example

Tags: measure-theory

I want to understand that for the following Measurable Transformation on $\mathbb R$, there is no invariant measure.

$T: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, T(x)=x^2+2$, could anyone help me to see that

$(1)$ $T^{-1} (x)\in (-\infty, x-1)\quad \forall x\ge 2 ?$

$(2)$ For any bounded set $A$, $\quad \exists n\in \mathbb N\quad \ni T^{-n}(A)=(T^{-1})^n(A)\in (-\infty, 2)$

$(3)$ Hence, $\mu(A)= (T^{-1})^n(A)=0$

Could anyone help me to understand the above facts?

Thanks!

I see $T(\mathbb R)=[2,\infty)$, so any invariant measure must be supported on $[2,\infty)$, this is clear.

To understand analytically $(1)$, I started doing $T(-\infty)=\infty, T(x-1)= x^2-2x+3$ but I am not getting the fact.

Comment: If $y\in T^{-1}(x)$ then $y^2+2=x$ then $y^2 = x-2$ and so $y\leq \sqrt{x-2}$. This should solve $(1)$. I really don't understand what you're trying to ask in $(2)$ or in $(3)$.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to understand an example of Trivial invariant measure on Real line

Comment: You made a big mistake in stating the problem. It appears that you want to consider measures $\mu$ such that $\mu \circ T^{-1} =\mu$ but you did not mention that in the body of the question.

Comment: I understand now the point Thank you KRM!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite positive measure such that $\mu \circ T^{-1}=\mu$. Let $A$ be a bounded measurable set and choose an integer $N$ such that $x <N$ for all $x \in A$. Then $T^{-1}A \subset (-\infty, N-1)$ by (1). More generally,  $T^{-n}A \subset (-\infty, N-n)$. Hence $\mu (A)=\mu T^{-n} (A) \leq \mu (-\infty, N-n)$ for every $n$. Since the intervals here decrease to empty set as $n$ increases to $\infty$ we get $\mu (A)=0$. Since this is true for every bounded set $A$ it follows that $\mu $ is the zero measure.

Comment: @miosaki There was a typo. I think the proof is clear now.